# Find number of pairs satisfying given absolute difference and product

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If I'm given absolute difference of two numbers and their product, how can I determine the number of ordered pairs possible?
What I have thought is - 
Total number of pairs possible may be 4, 2 or 0.
When d<0
ans=0
When d==0
if p==0
ans=1
else ans=2
For all other values of d
ans=4
Am I right? or am I missing some edge cases?

Comment: When $d=0,p\neq0$, why do you have __two__ pairs ? Your two numbers are the same, doesn't that leave _at most_ one pair ?

Comment: For d=0 and p=4, possible pairs are (2,2) and (-2,-2). No?

Comment: You're right, my bad, I thought you were working with positive integers. So, you're working on $\mathbb{Z}$, right ?

Comment: Yes, can you help figuring out other edge cases?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are right (I ran some computer simulation)s but I do not have a mathematical proof yet

Comment: Ah! no no! I'm not asking for these cases, I have verified all these cases. I want to know whether I am missing some corner cases/conditions or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you're just looking for all the cases/conditions, here's what I could add:

Let $a,b$ be the two integers satisfying $|a-b|=d,ab=p$.

- $d<0$

  $\rightarrow$ $0$ pairs possible
- $d=0$

  - $p=0$

    $\rightarrow$ $1$ pair possible $(0,0)$
  - $p\neq0$ : $a=b\neq0$

    $\rightarrow$ $2$ pairs if $p$ is a square $(a,b),(-a,-b)$

    **$\rightarrow$ $0$ pairs otherwise**
- $d>0$

  $\rightarrow$ $4$ pairs if the combination is possible $(a,b),(b,a),(-a,-b),(-b,-a)$

  **$\rightarrow$ $0$ pairs if the combination is not possible** (ex : $p=12,d=2$)

So, if we forget about the cases when there is no answer, what you wrote was true